# Number of Edges Proof for Complete Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

For any k with $ 0 \le k \le n$, prove ${n \choose 2} = {k \choose 2} + k(n - k) + {n - k \choose 2}$.

The question asks for it to be done algebraically, which I've already done. However, the second part asks you to not use any algebra whatsoever and to prove it using knowledge about complete graphs.

I know that ${n \choose 2}$ is equal to the number of edges in a complete graph, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Hint. What if you had two disjoint complete graphs and combined them by adding in all possible new edges? If you can prove it now you can answer your own question (that's acceptable on this site) - before someone else jumps in and does it.

Comment: Well you didn't get to the hint fast enough ... glad to see you accepted one of the right answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at a complete graph on $n$ vertices.

Partition it into two subgraphs, one on $k$ vertices and the other on $n-k$. We know that as complete graphs, each of them has $\binom k 2$ and $\binom {n-k} 2$ vertices, respectively. Now we want to join them to get the full $K_n$ graph. This means for any of the $k$ vertices in one, we need to connect it to all $n-k$ in the other graph, so we take the product $k(n-k)$.

Add everything up, and we obtain the identity you provided,
$$\binom n 2 = \binom k 2 + \binom {n-k} 2 + k(n-k)$$

Comment: I didn't think to separate the graph into two, that explains it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Divide the vertices into two parts $A$ and $B$, with $A$ having $k$ elements.

Edges are of three types:

(i) From a vertex in $A$ to a vertex in $A$. There are $\binom{k}{2}$ of these.

(ii) From a vertex in $B$ to a vertex in $B$. There are $\binom{n-k}{2}$ of those.

(iii) From a vertex in $A$ to one in $B$. There are $k(n-k)$ such, since the vertex in $A$ can be chosen in $k$ ways, and for each such vertex there are $n-k$ vertices in $B$ to join it to.